# file_put_contents not saving as image/png type

Tags: php, png

I am trying to save 10000+ images from some site using file_put_contents().

I have been searching for 7 hours, and no result. Same problem again and again.

Some images save as image/png, but some save as application/octet-stream. Why ?

All images are almost the same, PNG type, all 130x130px, but why some of them are saving as application/octet-stream ??

I am using this code to save images:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10110; $i++) {
     file_put_contents("img/".$i.".png", file_get_contents("http://*******.com/uploads/software-thumbnails/".$i.".png"));
}
```

Comment: Maybe you got banned?

Comment: I am not banned.. I am still able to save images again and again. But just specific 5000-6000 images are saving as application/octet-stream.

Comment: What do you mean "some images save as image/png, but some save as application/octet-stream" ? The MIME type is irrelevant here. They are saved as valid PNG files or not?

Comment: some are saved as valid PNG, and some not... don't know why..

Comment: But how do you check that they are invalid PNG?

Comment: I can not open them in any program.. Windows photo viewer, photoshop, paint, nor any other

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$content=file_get_contents(.....);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($content);
if ($im !== false) {
   imagepng($im, "img/".$i.".png");
}
```